# YouTube API: How can a 'non-business-owner' automate the upload process (public videos)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to upload videos through the google API in python to save some time. When I do so, the videos are automatically locked and I get the following email:

*...
We’re reaching out as it’s important you know that your video has been locked as private. This is because it was uploaded to YouTube using a third-party service that hasn’t yet been through our verification process.
...*

This raises two questions:

1. I trust this 'third-party service', cause its my own. Is there no way to enable that it doesn't get blocked?
2. When going through the verification process, I need to provide all sort of business data like business website and so on. Many YouTubers do not even have a business cause they are either not earning yet, or earn based on a freelancer status. I see why an audit is important, but I don't want to make this 'app' available for other users - it's just for myself (but I need to have an 'app' cause uploading without OAuth2 is not possible).

I read that Google engineers are monitoring the tags I provided on this question, so it would be great if I could get a statement on how a YouTuber without an official business can automate the upload process.

Comment: Have you tried marking the project as internal.  I have never seen a google engineer monitor or respond to a verification question they have better things to do.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its looking for a response from a Google engineer.   Author should contact Google for official google response.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're right, this is more a verification question that an engineering / coding one.

Good point, internal should actually solve this problem - need a G suite account though, which I am not sure is possible without a business - will look into it.

Comment: What does Gsuite have to do with Youtube API?  Setting the project on developer console to internal means that you will not be using it for others.

Comment: As seen on the screenshot [Link](https://ibb.co/qy3JRvF) it states:

Because you’re not a G Suite user, you can only make your app available to external (general audience) users.

Comment: I got this same message today and almost all my videos uploaded to YouTube have been locked down and set to private. Seems like we are facing the same issue. My personal advice is uploading videos with Python Selenium instead of our own YouTube API. But the problem is that how to solve the "upload action" with selenium which doesn't support. If I figure it out, I will come back and update this answer. Good luck, to both you and me.

Comment: yes selenium would work, but I want to run the python program on a linux server and access it through an endpoint. So I guess I'd rather pay $6 for a G suite google account + domain which is needed and set it to 'internal' as suggested by 'DalmTo'.
Thanks and good luck to you too.

Comment: @Christian Coenen: Most likely that you'll have to go through the verification process. While filling in the respective web form, why don't you try to set the fields related to business as `N/A`? (Disclaimer: I did not had to try this myself (yet!), but I remember that others proceeded this way.)

Comment: @stvar thanks, I'll try it with N/A and see what happens. But I honestly don't think they'll approve it.

Comment: It is said that Google engineers monitor these topics. Can we get a reply? Users can still upload through browser. So why it is not allowed to upload via API the same amount of videos?

Comment: Please share a way to get verified. In the mean time, i need to learn how to use selenium